# Only return rows with local max

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

The code below gives me something similar to the table below. What I am looking to do is only return the PROVID that has the max count per PATID.

```sql
SELECT  PAT_ID AS PATID
    , VISIT_PROV_ID AS PROVID
    , COUNT(*) AS PROVCOUNT
    FROM PAT_ENC
    GROUP BY PAT_ID, VISIT_PROV_ID
    ORDER BY PAT_ID, COUNT(*) DESC
```

| PATID | PROVID | PROVCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |

The table below would be the desired result based on the same data from the previous table.

| PATID | PROVID | PROVCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 |

Answer (score 1):

We can user `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PATID ORDER BY PROVCOUNT DESC)`, which gives a ranking of 1 to the row with largest value of PROVCOUNT for each PATID, in a CTE and then use `WHERE ranking = 1` to only show these largest values

> ```
> create table PAT_ENC (
> PATID int,
> PROVID    int,
> PROVCOUNT int);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO PAT_ENC (PATID, PROVID, PROVCOUNT) 
> SELECT 1, 3,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, 4,  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, 3,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, 8,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 3, 4,  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 4, 1,  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 4, 2,  3 FROM DUAL;
> ```

> ```
> WITH COUNTED AS
> (SELECT 
>   PATID, 
>   PROVID, 
>   PROVCOUNT,
>   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PATID ORDER BY PROVCOUNT DESC) ranking
> FROM PAT_ENC)
> SELECT
>   PATID, 
>   PROVID, 
>   PROVCOUNT
> FROM COUNTED
> WHERE ranking = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> PATID | PROVID | PROVCOUNT
> ----: | -----: | --------:
>     1 |      3 |         1
>     2 |      4 |         6
>     3 |      4 |         6
>     4 |      1 |         8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e2ab2c9cd1d4eb1030e782dab28d942)*